# Avoiding SSIS script task to convert utf-8 to unicode for AS400 data to SQL Server

Tags: character-encoding, ssis, ibm-midrange

After many tries I have concluded that the optimal way to transfer with SSIS data from AS400 (non-unicode) to SQL Server is:

1. Use native transfer utility to dump data to tsv (tab delimited)
2. Convert files from utf-8 to unicode
3. Use bulk insert to put them into SQL Server

In #2 step I have found a ready made code that does this:

```
string from = @"\\appsrv02\c$\bg_f0101.tsv";
        string to = @"\\appsrv02\c$\bg_f0101.txt";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(from, Encoding.UTF8, false, 1000000))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to, false, Encoding.Unicode, 1000000))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

I need to fully understand what is happening here with the encoding and why this is necessary.

How can I replace this script task with a more elegant solution?

Comment: What native transfer utility are you using?  Does it give you the ability to specify a desired destination CCSID?  If so, maybe you can use 1200, which corresponds to UTF-16 (a.k.a. Unicode in this context).

Comment: @dmc i am using the "Data Transfer from IBM i" utility that comes with the iSeries client software. Yes it does have the ability to specify CCSID and i am using 1208 for the above example. I tried many others including 1200 and it didn't work. I always get error when i try to run the package.

Comment: @dmc : See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794861/force-unicode-on-data-transfer-utility-for-iseries-as400-for-tsv-tab-delimited-f

Comment: @dmc: I'm not saying you're wrong, but I just want to understand: what makes you think "Unicode" means UTF-16 in this context? Is that a SQL Server thing? (I would not be surprised that something as boneheaded as `Encoding.Unicode` would be a Microsoft thing.)

Comment: @e4rthdog: I am getting the strong sense that you're using the term "Unicode" in a Microsoft-centric way. So when you're dealing with Microsoft stuff, I guess it's not *wrong*, exactly. But here you're interfacing with non-Microsoft stuff, and it will really help you communicate with non-Microsoft people if you can use more accepted terminology. (Trust me, I'm not dissing you. IBM is at least as bad as Microsoft when it comes to having their own wacky terminology.) But to people who actually deal with Unicode, "Unicode" is NOT, I repeat, **NOT** an encoding. In fact, that's the WHOLE POINT.

Comment: @JohnY Yes i am using these terms in ms context, and as i can see you are right..UTF-16LE should not be used as unicode in ms world...

Comment: @JohnY: According to Microsoft's documentation for `Encoding.Unicode` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx), it is a way to specify UTF-16LE in .NET.  I agree it has the potential to confuse, but I'm unable to edit my original comment to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much insight into exactly why you need the utf-8 conversion task,  except to say that SQL server - I believe - uses UCS-2 as its native storage format, and this is similiar to UTF-16 which is what your task converts the file to. I'm surprised SSIS can't work with a UTF-8 input source though.

My main point is to answer the "How could I replace this script task with a more elegant solution?":

I have had a lot of success using [HiT OLEDB/400 Server](http://www.hitsw.com/products_services/sql400/oledb400/oledb400svr.html). It allows you to set up your AS/400 / iSeries / System i / whatever IBM are calling it this week as a linked server in SQL server, and you can then access the 400's data directly from the server its linked to using the standard 4 part SQL syntax, e.g. SELECT * FROM my400.my400.myLib.myFile.
Or even better, it's much more efficient as a passthrough query using EXEC...AT.

Using this you would not need SSIS at all, you'd just need a simple stored proc with that does an insert into your destination table direct from the 400 data.